# How to Accept 2 different path using react-router v6 createBrowserRouter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router-dom` and `createBrowserRouter` to create the routes.

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <AuthLayout />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/:lang(en|es)/dashboard",
        element: <Dashboard />,
      },
      {
        path: "/:lang(en|es)/classifications",
        children: [
          { index: true, element: <Classifications /> },
          { path: "/:lang(en|es)/classifications/:id", element: <UpdateClassifications /> },
        ],
      }
    ],
  },
]);
```

I am getting an error:

> No routes matched location "/en/dashboard"

I need the routing except `"www.blabla/en/dashboard"` and `"www.blabla/es/dashboard"`, if URL is without `"en"` or `"es"` go to `"en"`.

All the examples I found don't use `createBrowserRouter`.

Answer (score 0):

React-Router-DOM v6 doesn't allow for regular expressions in the paths. You must use a regular path parameter and validate the values in the component.

Create a layout route component to handle specifically the `":lang"` path segment and test the `lang` path parameter, if it is valid then render an `Outlet` for the nested routes, otherwise render a redirect to the same page but with the `"en"` path segment.

Example:

```
import {
  Navigate,
  Outlet,
  useLocation,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

onst LangLayout = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { lang } = useParams();

  const validLang = /en|es/.test(lang);

  return validLang ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to={location.pathname.replace(lang, "en")} replace />
  );
};
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <AuthLayout />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: ":lang",
        element: <LangLayout />,
        children: [
          {
            path: "dashboard",
            element: <Dashboard />
          },
          {
            path: "classifications",
            children: [
              { index: true, element: <Classifications /> },
              {
                path: ":id",
                element: <UpdateClassifications />
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

### Demo

[image: Edit how-to-accept-2-different-path-using-react-router-v6-createbrowserrouter]